# Detect if anchor is linked to an ID

Tags: jquery

I wan to do a smooth scroll when an anchor is clicked, but first I want to check if the anchor link is linked to an `id`. if there is just hash then don'nt do the scroll.

Like:

```
<a href="#">do not scroll</a>

<a href="#anyID">Yes do the scroll</a>
```

My current code scroll on click every anchor which have just hash.

please fix my code so that it will not scroll if anchor has just hash

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash;

    if (typeof($(target).offset()) != 'undefined') {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 60
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that an element exist for each anchor that does not just contain a hash, then you could change your selector to:

```
$('a[href^="#"][href!="#"]')
```

Explicitly testing for the existence of the element is good too though.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this.href);

    if (target.length && target.is(':visible')) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 60
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Got error Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://url.com/home#experiance

Comment: it looks like an syntax error in the javascript... can you check the line number

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function(){
 var href=$(this).attr('href');
 if(href!="#"){
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(href).offset().top - 60
  }, 1000);
 }
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't change the selector. Now you will also select `a` elements which link to external pages. And `$('http://....')` will throw a syntax error for sure.

Comment: sorry i didn't get you. please elaborate

Comment: `$('a')` will also select elements such as `<a href="http://example.com"></a>`, i.e. links to external sides. `if (href!="#")` will be true (obvious I hope). Later you pass the `href` value to jQuery (`$(href)`) and since `href = "http://example.com"`, jQuery will throw an error, because it is not a valid selector. You should keep the OP's selector: `$('a[href^="#"]')`.